no such instruction: `isb 0xF', number of operands mismatch for `ds', no such instruction: `cpsie i'
I'm encountering compiler errors while attempting to conduct unit tests on a C codebase using VectorCast. Specifically, the errors pertain to unrecognized instructions such as dmb, isb, and cpsie i.
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s: Assembler messages:Assembler messages:
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:150: Error: no such instruction: `isb 0xF'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:196: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:242: Error: no such instruction: `dmb 0xF'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:288: Error: no such instruction: `cpsie i'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:334: Error: no such instruction: `cpsid i'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:398: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:434: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:506: Error: no such instruction: `dmb 0xF'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:545: Error: number of operands mismatch for `ds'
\AppData\Local\Temp\cc39Jhsm.s:572: Error: no such instruction: `isb 0xF'

I found these instructions in the cmsis_gcc.h file. I tried to replace the inline assembly instructions with __NOP(); instructions, but this resulted in link errors.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve these compiler errors and successfully conduct the unit tests.
